# SO's hardware superiority

Tags: performance

I found [this link](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html) about stack overflow's great performance. Here it says

`Stack Overflow still uses a scale-up strategy. No clouds in site. With their SQL Servers loaded with 384 GB of RAM and 2TB of SSD, AWS would cost a fortune. The cloud would also slow them down, making it harder to optimize and troubleshoot system issues. Plus, SO doesn’t need a horizontal scaling strategy. Large peak loads, where scaling out makes sense, hasn’t  been a problem because they’ve been quite successful at sizing their system correctly.`

From what I understand, here they do not use the cloud. So what do they use for this kind of magic ?
Where are these Sql servers they are talking about?

p.s. Also if this question does not belong here, please tell me where I should post this ?

Comment: I think you should post this on meta.

Comment: @simonzack I wanted to, but i did not have that reputation. :) I'm very new to stack overflow.

Comment: Not saying this is not interesting. But this is off-topic, and would be a bad question even for [sf]. StackOverflow is great but seriously everyone, stop behaving like fanboys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what do they use for this kind of magic?

Servers. You know. The type you can order from Dell, HP, SUperMicro. CLouds normally are slow and expensive compared to an exclusive setup. For example ou small SQL Server in my company now goes to 6tp this month - all SSD. Get me that in the cloud.

> Where are these Sql servers

In a data center. This is called colocation. You rent space in a data center. Commodity buiness for 20 years or so.

Comment: They also greatly over-provision their machines. The link says they could run the cite on 5 machines but they have 25.